# Retrieve citations in a text

Tags: python

I want to build a module of an app that retrieves citations from a given text. For citation recognition, I've started by using regular expressions to recognize patterns followed by citations styles. I implemented it for [APA citation style](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations) and [Vancouver](https://biblio.laurentian.ca/research/fr/guides/citer-ses-sources) citation style. I used respectively the following regular expressions :

```
apa_format_pattern = r'\(([^"\)]*|\bAnonymous\b|\bAnonyme\b|"[^"\)]*")(, )([\d]+|n\.d\.|[\d]+[\w])\)'
```

thanks to [José](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/count-citations-in-a-word-document-with-python-and-regular-expressions-d068218c50b9)
and

```
vancouver_format_pattern = r'(\[(\d+(, \d+)*)\])'
```

My concern is that those regular expressions can only retrieve the in-text references actually not the actual citations made. I would like to retrieve the actual citation made in the text not just the reference of it.

What is the feasibility of this ? Do you know any helpful tool? I did some searches but I haven't found yet a solution to get the whole citation. Your help is very welcome.